# Using install4j updater with FTP

Tags: install4j

I am trying to configure the updater using an FTP link.
In the "check for update" action I set the URL to:

`ftp://USER:PASSWORD@ftp.acme.com/MyProgram/Update/updates.xml`

Using Wireshark I can see that `updates.xml` is downloaded correctly.
The problem arises in the "Download URL" action later where the URL set by:

```
((UpdateDescriptorEntry)context.getVariable("updateDescriptorEntry"))
    .getURL().toExternalForm()
```

Is correct except it lacks USER and PASSWORD; I fixed the problem modifying the script:

```
String s = ((UpdateDescriptorEntry)context.getVariable("updateDescriptorEntry"))
               .getURL().toExternalForm().toString();
s = s.replaceFirst("ftp.acme.com", "USER:PASSWORD@ftp.acme.com");
return s;
```

Is there a more clean way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For this special case, you have to set the "Base URL for installers" on the Installer->Auto-Update options step.